# Error: Is a 'method' but is used as a 'type'

Tags: c#

I'm running a time and attendance log program using Delegates and events.

I've this piece of code in the class part:

```
class DelegateEvent
{
    public Delegate AttendanceLogHandler(string Message);
    public event AttendanceLogHandler EventLog;
    public void LogProcess()
    {

      // Executable statements.

    }
```

And in the main stream I've the below code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AttendanceLogger FileLog = new AttendanceLogger("C:\\process.log");
        DelegateEvent DEvent = new DelegateEvent();
        DEvent.EventLog += new DelegateEvent.AttendanceLogHandler(Logger);
        DEvent.EventLog += new DelegateEvent.AttendanceLogHandler(FileLog.Logger);
        DEvent.LogProcess();
        Console.ReadLine();
        FileLog.Close();
    }
```

The `AttendanceLogHandler` that I've used in the main stream is throwing an error stating:

`' timenattndncelog.DelegateEvent.AttendanceLogHandler (string)' is 'method' but is used as a 'type'`

Can you please help me in eliminating this error?

Comment: What is AttendanceLogger?

Comment: Is your code compiling? your delegate is missing a return type: public Delegate AttendanceLogHandler(string Message);

Comment: AttendanceLogger is a class that encapsulates the file I/O and is a constructor as well.

Comment: Logger is a member function that is used in the delegate.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov these are the compilation errors only. actually the delegate is defined in sucha manner that encapsulates and returns no value that means the the delegate "public delegate AttendanceLogHandler(string Message);" should be actually  "public delegate void AttendanceLogHandler(string Message); But that is again returning an error stating "The 'void' token is not valid an a class, structure, or interface member declaration"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
public Delegate AttendanceLogHandler(string Message);
```

to

```
public delegate void AttendanceLogHandler(string Message);
       ^        ^
```

Note the small `d` and `void` return type. using `Delegate` makes the compiler to think you are actually creating a method with return type `Delegate`. To create a delegate type you should use `delegate` keyword, not `Delegate` type.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate should be defined with a lowercase d and a return type.  Here is some sample code that should help:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AttendanceLogger logger = new AttendanceLogger();
        DelegateEvent dEvent = new DelegateEvent();
        dEvent.EventLog += new DelegateEvent.AttendanceLogHandler(logger.LogMessage);
        dEvent.LogProcess();
    }
}

class DelegateEvent
{
    public delegate void AttendanceLogHandler(string message);
    public event AttendanceLogHandler EventLog;
    public void LogProcess()
    {
        EventLog("Delegate Event Called");
    }
}

class AttendanceLogger
{
    public AttendanceLogger() { }

    public void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttendanceLogger: " + message);
    }

    private string m_logFile;
}
```

A side note, you should not need to put the "new DelegateEvent.Attendance..." part in.  You can just pass "logger.LogMessage" as in:

```
dEvent.EventLog += logger.LogMessage;
```